# use the definition for an integral domain to prove that Z7 is an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

```
Integral Domain
```

Divisors
    7 is prime 
    〖[a]〗_7 〖[b]〗_7=〖[0]〗_7∈Z_7
    〖[ab]〗_7=〖[0]〗_7
    ab∈[0]_7
    ab is multiple of 7
    a∈[0]_7 and b ∈ 〖[0]〗_7
    If  〖[a]〗_7=〖[0]〗_7 and 〖[b]〗_7=〖[0]〗_7,then  Z_7  has no zero divisors.
Did I prove non zero divisors correctly.
How do I prove Multiplicative identity(unity) and Multiplication is commutative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the right idea: Z7 is an integral domain if its a ring and ab = 0 implies a = 0 or b = 0.

The key is that 7 is a prime number. Recall that "x = 0" in Z7 means x is a multiple of 7: $7 | x$.

So you can now use euclids lemma: $7 | ab$ implies $7 | a$ or $7 | b$ to show that you have an integral domain.

Comment: can you please help me out with the multiplicative identity and multiplication communative

Comment: @MichaelAnthonyPryor, sure

Answer (score 0):

as for identity: 1 is the identity and since $1x = x$ in integers the same is true when you move to Z7: $[1][x] = [x]$.

Commutativity is the same: In Z: $xy = yx$ so in Z7: $[x][y] = [y][x]$.